# jquery ajax load more button with multiple instances

Tags: jquery, ajax

how to use this code multiple times on the same page?

Im displaying data that will be grabbed with ajax and each one has its own comment box with the "show more comments" button.

Its like if I press the "show more comments" button, each comment box will get updated - instead of the one which was clicked.

I think I'll need to modify the Jquery/ajax code:

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.loadmore', function () {
     $(this).text('Loading...');
     var ele = $(this).parent('li');
      $.ajax({
        url: 'loadmore.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          page:$(this).data('page'),
        },
        success: function(response){
          if(response){
            ele.hide();
            $(".news_list").append(response);
          }
        }
      });
});
```

HTML/PHP:

```
<div id="container">
<ul class="news_list">
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 0 , $resultsPerPage");
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$title=$data['name'];
$content=$data['comment'];
echo "<li><h3>$title</h3><p>$content<p></li>";
}
?>
<li class="loadbutton"><button class="loadmore" data-page="2">Load More</button></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

loadmore.php:

```
    <?php include('config.php'); ?>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['page'])):
        $paged=$_POST['page'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `comments`ORDER BY `id` ASC";
        if($paged>0){
               $page_limit=$resultsPerPage*($paged-1);
               $pagination_sql=" LIMIT  $page_limit, $resultsPerPage";
               }
        else{
        $pagination_sql=" LIMIT 0 , $resultsPerPage";
        }

        $result=mysql_query($sql.$pagination_sql);

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num_rows>0){
        while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $title=$data['name'];
        $content=$data['comment'];
        echo "<li><h3>$title</h3><p>$content<p></li>";
        }
        }
        if($num_rows == $resultsPerPage){?>
        <li class="loadbutton"><button class="loadmore" data-page="<?php echo  $paged+1 ;?>">Load More</button></li>
     <?php 
      }else{
        echo

 "<li class='loadbutton'><h3>No More Feeds</h3></li>";
 }
  endif;
   ?>
```

any suggestions?

regards

Comment: share your html sample

Answer (score 0):

For each instance, Change the classes of your buttons and the divs where the content will be displayed. Such as the loa dmore button should have the following classes

```
<li class="loadbutton1"><button class="loadmore1" data-page="2">Load More</button></li>

<li class="loadbutton2"><button class="loadmore2" data-page="2">Load More</button></li>

<li class="loadbutton3"><button class="loadmore3" data-page="2">Load More</button></li>
```